# django authorization

Tags: django, authentication

Needed authorization. Have read a couple of articles, read about all inbuild mechanisms, take it and do it. He started to do.

Registration took module `django-registration`, wrote Login myself, used lib `django.contrib.auth`. Goes as follows: I login at the login page, seems like all is good  but when I go to another page authorization miraculously disappears. As I understand it, authorization didn't write to session and I get auth only at login page.

I did the following:

1. Authorized on the login page.
2. Recorded the whole `User` object to `session`.
3. On each page, the first thing I check when the page loads is whether there is `User` in session data, and if so, read it from there.

The source looks like this:

```
def login_user(request):
state = "Please log in below..."
username = password = ''
if request.POST:
    username = request.POST.get('username')
    password = request.POST.get('password')

    user = authenticate(username=username, password=password)
    if user is not None:
        if user.is_active:
            login(request, user)
            state = "You're successfully logged in!"
        else:
            state = "Your account is not active, please contact the site admin."
    else:
        state = "Your username and/or password were incorrect."
    request.session['user'] = user
    return render(request,'auth.html',{'state':state, 'username': username, 'info':'info'})
```

and page where I read from `session`:

```
@csrf_protect
def home(request):
    if "user" in request.session:
        user = request.session['user']
    else:
        user = None
    return render_to_response('home.html', {'user_name' : user}, context_instance = RequestContext(request))
```

But I think, it's a very stupid way. Can you suggest a more appropriate way?

Answer (score 1):

I am not really sure what you want to achieve. As soon as a user is logged in, you can acces `request.user.is_authenticated()` to check for an authenticated user in your view or access `request.user` for the user itself.

Answer (score 0):

You don't need to add users to the session; this is done automatically by the authentication middleware.

You also don't need to manually check for users; use the [`login_required` decorator](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/auth/#the-login-required-decorator).

Combining this, your login view becomes:

```
def login_user(request):
    state = "Please log in below..."
    username = password = ''
    if request.POST:
        username = request.POST.get('username')
        password = request.POST.get('password')
    else:
        return redirect('login/')

    user = authenticate(username=username, password=password)
    if user is not None:
        if user.is_active:
            login(request, user)
            state = "You're successfully logged in!"
        else:
            state = "Your account is not active, please contact the site admin."
    else:
        state = "Your username and/or password were incorrect."
    return render(request,'auth.html',{'state':state, 'info':'info'})
```

And in your other views:

```
from django.contrib.auth.decorators import login_required
from django.shortcuts import render

@csrf_protect
@login_required
def home(request):
    return render(request, 'home.html')
```

In your template (from the [documentation](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/auth/#authentication-data-in-templates)):

```
{% if user.is_authenticated %}
    <p>Welcome, {{ user.username }}. Thanks for logging in.</p>
{% else %}
    <p>Welcome, new user. Please log in.</p>
{% endif %}
```